# Querying a has_many_through join table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have an app in Rails 5 where I have the following relationships:

User model

```
has_many :consult_users
has_many :consults, through: :consult_users
```

Consult Model

```
 has_many :consult_users
 has_many :users, through: :consult_users
```

ConsultUser Model (Join Table)

```
  belongs_to :consult
  belongs_to :user
```

In a controller I need to list out all of the consults for a given user. So in the English list all consults which have a join record `consult_users` and the `consult_users.user_id` equals the `current_user.id`

I'm having a really tough time mowing through this and was wondering if anyone could give me a tip on how to write this query to get an array of all Consults which meet this query.

I've tried raw SQL and also ActiveRecord but I am hitting a wall.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If everything is set up correctly, `user.consults` should work, what happens when you run that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to use the associations for that eg:

```
current_user.consults
```

Comment: I have no idea why I was overcomplicating this.  Feel like a complete moron.  Thanks for the gentle slap on the back of the head. :)

Comment: :D sometimes we overthink these things... but TBH they're the best problems to have... fresh eyes mean the problem is solved quickly. I'd rather that than have a problem where everyone else looks at it and tells you they're totally stumped too ;)

Comment: You make a really good point, thanks again for your help.  Almost no sleep and 5 years of Rails knowledge fell out of my head :)